# Tag Synonym: unit-tests -> unit-testing

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-merge

I was just doing some STCI cleanup for [stci-software-engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stci-software-engineering) and noticed that there was both a [unit-tests](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-tests) and [unit-testing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing) tag. There are only 8 questions tagged [unit-tests](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-tests), 7 of which are also tagged [unit-testing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing). There are also over 250 questions tagged [unit-testing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing).

I don't see the need to keep both, but wanted to see the community's take on this before I did anything. Is there a reason why both tags are relevant, especially when one almost always exists with the other?

Comment: They are [synonyms on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/unit-testing/synonyms).

Comment: @YannisRizos Didn't even think to check SO, but that's a good point. It seems to indicate that it might be a good idea. I'm just trying to think of a case here, though, where there is a difference. I can't come up with one, but if someone can within the context of Programmers, that's good enough for me to not synonymize them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am all for making these synonyms - created an "official" suggestion for that.

It's now up to those having a right to vote whether to approve or reject,

> ...Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.
>
> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdKuA.jpg]

### update

As of now, suggested synonymizing is done (thanks to [Thomas](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/tag-synonym-unit-tests-unit-testing/3337#comment8857_3337) and all who voted).

Comment: Hmmm, we (mods) could have merged the tags and save everyone the trouble (although we only need one more vote now). But reminding people they can suggest and vote synonyms on their own works too... Keep the artwork coming ;)

Comment: My plan was to mod merge if no one had objections, but we're 1 vote away from the community handling this, and I'd rather the community handle this through non-moderator-actions. If it doesn't have that vote by the time I get home from work, I'll probably mod merge it (unless someone gives a good reason not to before then), since it's at 3 votes now.

Comment: @ThomasOwens given long list of [top users in the tag](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/unit-testing/topusers) having a right to vote, I'd be rather surprised to see if community can't handle it :)

Comment: It didn't get there, so I forced it. Based on the upvotes on the question and suggestions, it seems like the community was behind this. It only needed one more vote, anyway, so it wasn't a major override of community thought.

Comment: Very off topic but may I ask what you use for screenshots?

Comment: @Jae `PrtScr` button to capture screen and MS Paint for, well, painting (Windows)

Answer (score 2):

I see no difference really unless we want to assume that [unit-testing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing) is a methodology or practice and [unit-tests](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-tests) is actually about unit tests as an individual programming artifact of unit testing.  Unit testing could also encompass such things as Mocking, which is an important strategy for handling dependencies in unit tests.

It all depends on where we want to draw the line.  Personally I feel that discerning between the two is just too granular.  I believe this even more so in that it is probably universal that one cannot be practicing unit testing without creating unit tests, the core functionality.  I do feel however that mocking is different enough to deserve its own tag because it is a clear strategy to approach certain unit tests.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mocking ;p

Comment: @YannisRizos Good suggestion!  I wrote an improved tag wiki on [tag:mocking].  I also added a synonym for [tag:mocks] so please take the opportunity to vote on this synonym please.